# Is it possible to "hide" a .gif inside a .jpg?

Tags: animation, png, jpeg, gif, converters

I've made an animated png-file from a gif and want it to be my cover of one of my spotify playlists. Spotify however only supports jpg-files. I've tried everything to somehow upload the gif/animated png but spotify either says "wrong file" or "it's not a .jpg even it has this extension".

But there exists at least one playlist that has an animated cover (clickable):

[image]
<sub>(source: [scdn.co](https://pl.scdn.co/images/pl/default/4ae05f4759a5600be931e86b9850b7c772ca89aa))</sub>

So I think it is not entirely impossible. Is there any way to disguise an animated png or any other animated file as a jpg-file so that the spotify algorithm won't deny the file as "not a jpg"?

Answer (score 0):

The file your URL points to is nothing more than a GIF file having a `.jpeg` extension and containing an additional XMP data block. This is the block in its entirety:

```
?xpacket begin="\xEF\xBB\xBF" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?> <x:xmpmta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.3-c011 66.145661, 2012/02/06-14:56:27        "><rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sTpe/ResourceRef#" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID="xmp.did:841355A4132068118083B7DA9A8DC98" xmpMM:DocumentID="xmp.did:FA726C2A111C11E69036DFC090D5CCE2" xmpMM:nstanceID="xmp.iid:F7A05810110B11E69036DFC090D5CCE2" xmp:CreatorTool="Adoe Photoshop CS6 (Macintosh)"> <xmpMM:DerivedFrom stRef:instanceID="xmp.iid:987E00694F2068118083B7D9A8DCF98" stRef:documentID="xmp.did:841355A4132068118083B7DA9A8DC98"/> </rdf:Description> </rdf:RDF> </x:xmpmeta> <?xpacket end="r"?>
```

*N.B.:* Pay attention to the `xmpMM:nstanceID` part instead of `xmpMM:instanceID` as it needs to be. This is not a transcription error, it`s an error in the file itself. Also note that there is no opening angular bracket in the block.

Have you attempted to upload this file back to Spotify? There may be 2 possible outcomes:

1. It fails to upload. That`d mean there used to be a way to upload GIFs but now it`s gone.
2. It succeeds. If so, look very closely at that XMP block and try to embed it in your GIF. Maybe it`s the XMP that makes Spotify declare the image suitable.